# scrapy didn't crawl all link

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to extract data from http://community.sellfree.co.kr/.  Scrapy is working, however it appears to only scrape the `start_urls`, and doesn't crawl any links.

I would like the spider to crawl the entire site.

The following is my code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from metacritic.items import MetacriticItem
class MetacriticSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "metacritic" # Name of the spider, to be used when crawling
    allowed_domains = ["sellfree.co.kr"] # Where the spider is allowed to go
    start_urls = [
        "http://community.sellfree.co.kr/"
    ]
    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*',))
          ,callback="parse", follow= True),
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response) # The XPath selector
        sites = hxs.select('/html/body')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = MetacriticItem()
            item['title'] = site.select('//a[@title]').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

There are two kinds of links on the page.  One is `onclick="location='../bbs/board.php?bo_table=maket_5_3'` and another is `<a href="../bbs/board.php?bo_table=maket_5_1&amp;sca=프로그램/솔루션"><span class="list2">solution</span></a>`

How can I get the crawler to follow both kinds of links?

Comment: You should inherit from `CrawlSpider`: try with `class MetacriticSpider(CrawlSpider):`

Comment: try rule : rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://www.sellfree.co.kr/.*(\.html)$")), callback='parse_item', follow=True),] or allow="http://www.sellfree.co.kr/"... try plating with regex in allowable links

Comment: there are two kind of link exist in sellfree.co.kr.

Comment: vipul sharma,thanks for your reply but your solution is not working.sorry

Comment: paul,it no matter whether using crawlspider or not

Comment: To use the rules you need the `CrawlSpider` AND DO NOT override the `parse` method, try `parse_item` as the other user suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Before I get started, I'd highly recommend using an updated version of Scrapy.  It appears you're still using an old one, as many of the methods/classes you're using have been moved around or deprecated.

To the problem at hand: the `scrapy.spiders.BaseSpider` class will not do anything with the `rules` you specify.  Instead, use the `scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider` class, which has functionality to handle rules built into.

Next, you'll need to switch your `parse()` method to a new name, since the the `CrawlSpider` uses `parse()` internally to work. (We'll assume `parse_page()` for the rest of this answer)

To pick up all basic links, and have them crawled, your link extractor will need to be changed.  By default, you shouldn't use regular expression syntax for domains you want to follow.  The following will pick it up, and your `DUPEFILTER` will filter out links not on the site:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('')), callback="parse_page", follow=True),
)
```

As for the `onclick=...` links, these are JavaScript links, and the page you are trying to process relies on them heavily.  Scrapy cannot crawl things like `onclick=location.href="javascript:showLayer_tap('2')"` or `onclick="win_open('./bbs/profile.php?mb_id=wlsdydahs'`, because it can't execute `showLayer_tap()` or `win_open()` in Javascript.

*(the following is untested, but should work and provide the basic idea of what you need to do)*

You can write your own functions for parsing these, though. For instance, the following can handle `onclick=location.href="./photo/"`:

```
def process_onclick(value):
    m = re.search("location.href=\"(.*?)\"", value)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
```

Then add the following rule (this only handles tables, expand it as needed):

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(''), tags=('table',), 
                       attrs=('onclick',), process_value=process_onclick), 
     callback="parse_page", follow=True),
```